# Uniqueness of the limit and finiteness of the measure space

Tags: lebesgue-measure, pointwise-convergence, almost-everywhere

We know that the convergence almost surely/everywhere implies the convergence in probability/measure.

But is this also true when the measure space is not sigma finite since this can lead to different limits?

I'll explain myself with an example:

Consider $(\mathcal{R}, \mathcal{B(\mathcal{R})}, \lambda)$ the real line with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and set with n $\in$ N:

$$
f_n(x) := \textbf{1}_{n,n+1} (x)
$$

**Convergence almost everywhere** happens since, if we pick an x into the interval and push n to infinity, there's the pointwise convergence and so also the almost everywhere.

**Convergence in measure** in this case:
$$
lim \lambda [f_n > \epsilon] = lim \lambda([n,n+1]) = lim 1 \neq 0 
$$
Conclusion, there's no convergence in measure.

I suppose that this is happening since the lebesgue measure on R is not finite and so it's not possible to do this implication. Is that correct or am I missing anything?

Comment: Almost everywhere convergence only implies convergence in measure on *finite* measure spaces. Your example shows that finiteness is necessary.

Comment: I think you mean that this condition is necessary in order to ensure that implication. However, Is this the only implication that is not anymore true in a measure space not finite? For example, is still true that uniform implies pointwise that implies a.e?

Comment: There are lots of statements which become false on infinite measure spaces. For example, Egorov's theorem (a.e. convergence implies uniform convergence except on a small set) becomes false on infinite measure spaces. However, it is true that uniform convergence $\implies$ pointwise convergence $\implies$ a.e. convergence regardless of measure space, by definition.

Comment: Thank you! Would you suggest any reading/book where may i find anything about these statements which become false on infinite measure spaces?

Comment: Here is a helpful diagram illustrating the relationship between different modes of convergence: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/

I also suggest Terry Tao's Intro to Measure Theory for a detailed discussion of various modes of convergence.